# Visual Basic 6 How to use Exceptions?

Tags: vb6

I have looked all over the Internet for an answer that addresses exception handling in VB6 and can't find anything useful. I want to show an error to the user and halt execution of the program where it encountered that error, I don't want execution to continue.

I've looked into using `End` but this isn't what I'm looking for. `End` closes all forms and exits. I've also used `Stop` but that temporary suspends execution.

I'm looking to handle logic exceptions if possible with this version of Visual Basic. If exceptions aren't available, is there a way to emulate them?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen with `halt execution of the program`?

Comment: Hi Brian, What I am looking for is a mechanism that emulates a try catch block. If the program encounters an error, the program should halt right where it is, but should be able to recover gracefully once a message is shown to the user. Thanks for the help, Brian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a template I use in all my projects:

```
Private Sub Test()
   On Error GoTo catch

   'your code which may cause an error

   'if you wanted to raise a user-defined error which start at 513
   Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "MyModule", "MyMessage"   

finally:
   'any code that always has to happen
   Exit Sub

catch:
   'logging, message boxes, etc, however you want to handle the error
   MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
   Resume finally
End Sub
```

Comment: To add to this code pattern, this is the VB documentation on the `On Error` statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa266173(v=vs.60)

Comment: Brian, thank you! I've never seen this way of doing it, but I'll implement it. Thank you again!

Comment: Brian or @MarkL, is there a way to show the user *my* error description in the catch block? So, if I did this in another language, it might look like: `Try If Something = "" Then Throw New Exception("This is my error message I'd like to show the user") End If Catch...`

Comment: @NaN Using Err.Raise would be similar.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, Thank you, Brian.

Comment: As Brian states, `Err.Raise` is the vb6 version of throwing a new exception. But that, by itself, is not displaying to the user. Instead, after the `catch` label, add the test desired and display to the user with `MsgBox` a customized message.

Comment: @MarkL, I'm still playing with `Err.Raise` and just noticed that I can't echo anything to the user without custom error blocks. Is this right?

Comment: @MarkL This code will show a MsgBox with "MyMessage" so I'm unclear what you mean.  Although your suggestion is another way to go about it.

Comment: I'm still having an issue halting execution. Even with the On Error statement and custom handler, I'm still not able to stop the program from moving to the next function or sub in the application. This is what I'm using: `CustomerErr5:Err.Clear MsgBox "This is a custom error"Exit Sub`. I think the `exit sub` still allows execution to continue.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, just trying to describe to OP that a (customized) message can be displayed in the "catch block", as your code example is displaying (just) the thrown error number and error description.

Comment: @NaN That is what I would expect to happen.  Either execution is going to continue, the app is going to crash with an unhandled error, or you force a stop with End.  However, one way to achieve what you want is to have your method return a value.  Then based upon the return value you can either skip or execute other methods.

Comment: I am reading another thread now where someone answered with `On Error is not structured error handling (i.e. it's nothing like try/catch blocks)`. If this be the case, then maybe what I should do is to use a function that returns a boolean value, then encompass the continuing code in that. Does this sound like what I need to be doing in order to halt execution in a certain place?

Comment: @NaN Yes, VB6 doesn't have "structured" error handling, but this technique mimics it fairly well.  Between this technique and having methods return a value you can usually achieve what you need.

Comment: Excellent, Brian, thank you so very much for the help! I'm really out of my comfort zone with VB6. Can you tell me if when I call the function, do I use `Call MyFunction`? If so, how do I assign the returned value to a variable? Maybe, `If Call MyFunction = True Then...`?

Comment: @BrianMStafford, I figured it out. I don't need the `Call` directive. Thanks again! ....and also thanks to MarkL

Comment: Plus one and if the OP wants to read more about `On Error` in VB6, this [concepts part of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa716196(v=vs.60)) is pretty good

Comment: Thanks for posting the link to the docs. This is the first time I've been able to find them!